# PhpMyadmin times out with small SQL file

Tags: mysql, php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to upload bump to phpmyadmin, which has has only 2MB but it has 12 thousand lines.

I always get this error:

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

I have 
`max_input_time = 1000`
`max_execution_time = 1000`

Comment: There are several php.ini settings which could restrict execution time, upload size or memory usage for php etc. Create a php file containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and open it in your browser to check those values (max upload, max execution_time and memory_limit).

Comment: Import via shell: `mysql -u username -p password database_name < filename.sql`

Comment: I have 
`max_input_time = 1000
max_execution_time = 1000`

And file is SMALL around 2MB. So upload size it's not really, it setted up on 120MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to edit apache2 main config and incrase `TimeOut`.

```
TimeOut 600
```